# Is it possible get value of an AJAX success variable in other file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a file.tpl with a basic script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ...        
    console.dir(resultdata);
    ...
</script>
```

Then I have another file.js with this function:

```
function editProductAttribute (url, parent){
    $.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(resultdata) {
    ...
    }
}
```

What I need is, to run console.dir(resultdata) in file.tpl, when ajax request inside editProductAttribute() is completed.

Consider, that only file.tpl can be modified, file.js should stay untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ajax request is global (which is by default) try that:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
});
```

But this will be fired on all ajax requests, you need to filter it in some way.

Comment: Would it also work if resultdata was global in scope?

Comment: ajax is async so you should never used any global value. But here, responseText property should be the value returned by the request so equal to resultdata

Comment: yes, that works fine. Is there any way to filter these results by the name of functions that were used to make the call?

Comment: @Amazzing filter it by `settings.url`

Comment: yes, this works too. Now I get just one result. This is what I needed. You're a true master :)
I just wonder if listening to all ajaxSuccess-es has a big impact on site performance?